# Flutter firebase_messaging Background Handler not Executing but Messages are Arriving on iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got firebase_messaging 9.1.0 receiving and showing both my Android and iOS apps notifications when the app is in the foreground, in the background, and closed. However on iOS the background handler future doesn't appear to be executing. I'm running the firebase_messaging_example app it doesn't print 'Handling a background message ${message.messageId}' when running in the background.

Background fetch and remote notifications are checked in xcode.

I've tried:

Sending notifications with and without  clickAction: "FLUTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

With and without

> ```
> <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
> <false/>
> ```

in info.plist

With and without background processing checked in xcode.

I'd like the background handler to execute some code that sets a badge on the app launcher icon. Does anyone know how to get the handler to work with iOS or another way to set a badge on the launcher icon when the app is closed?

Comment: Is this happening for both data and non data bearing notifications? Also, are you sure you didn't dismiss the notification? On iOS you have to manually enable them again/open the app for them to be displayed again. On iOS you have the option to set notification settings in Flutter by configuring sound/banner/alert.

Comment: Yes, it happens with and without data. The notifications are coming through, they're just not activating the background handler. On android, when the app is in the background I can see print it in the debug console and I can execute the code that shows a badge, but in iOS there's nothing. The sound/badge/alert options are just for when the app is running in the foreground. 

Could it matter what is in the data?

Comment: Please post your handler for background messages.

Comment: I'm using the unmodified example from the firebase_messaging package at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart
<br/>
The handler is:
<br/>
`Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}`

Comment: Kindly check my answer, I believe it will help you handle your situation.

Comment: Hi Adam, Have you found any solution to this problem? I am also facing this problem. Kindly let me know how to solve this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your replies in the comments section, please try to use this:

This is your top level function, above of `void main()`

```
 Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
     if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) await Firebase.initializeApp();
     print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
    }


handleNotifications() async {
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(badge: true, alert: true, sound: true);//presentation options for Apple notifications when received in the foreground.

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
print('Got a message whilst in the FOREGROUND!');
return;
}).onData((data) {
print('Got a DATA message whilst in the FOREGROUND!');
print('data from stream: ${data.data}');
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) async {
  print('NOTIFICATION MESSAGE TAPPED');
return;
}).onData((data) {
print('NOTIFICATION MESSAGE TAPPED');
print('data from stream: ${data.data}');
});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .getInitialMessage()
      .then((value) => value != null ? _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler : false);
return;
}
```

Then,
Inside void main, write it like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  handleNotifications(); 
  runApp(MyAppState());
}
```

Please let me know what happens after this, but this is most likely going to solve your problem.

Comment: It's still behaving the same way. The notifications arrive in the foreground, background, and when the app is closed. However the "Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');" still does not show up when the app is in the background. I tried with and without data.

Comment: print something besides `${message.messageId}');"`, does it work?
i.e `print('displayingTest message instead of message ID')`. It could be something in the `message.messageId`. Can you confirm this please?

Comment: Thanks for help. It didn't work either though. I'm just going to have my notification server get the data and send it in the payload rather than have the app handle things when the notification comes in.